# Extract mail comments - cannot find method

Tags: vba, outlook

I am creating a project to extract comments from mail messages in Outlook, however I can not find the method to access these.

Would you have any idea of how to do this?

Column and content to be extracted
[image: Column and content to be extracted]

Comment: What comments? How were they added to begin with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to extract the `PR_COMMENT_W` property. The DASL name is `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3004001F`. It should be accessed through the following method:

```
MailItem.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty
```

Answer (score 0):

```
REM Example of code that get the comment from a selected mail:
Const PR_COMMENT_W As String = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3004001f"
Dim oMail As Outlook.MailItem
Set oMail = ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
msgbox (oMail.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_COMMENT_W) )
```